# RKObjectManager's deleteObject with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

When trying to send a DELETE request to the server with an object, RestKit is trying to reference a deallocated object if you populate the `success` block like so:

```
[[APIClient objectManager] deleteObject:object path:path parameters:nil 
success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
  success();
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  failure([error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

The `success()` callback does nothing at the moment since I noticed that RestKit automatically deletes the local Core Data object for us.

If I set the `success` block to `nil`, then all is good with the world, but I'd rather have a way of knowing that it was successful.

I'm guessing that it's trying to reference the deleted object in the mapping result, but I can't be sure.  The server just returns a `no content` header so there's nothing to map.

Is there something that I could be doing wrong to cause this?

Comment: Call your block something else (so it's clear during discussion) - does the block you're calling exist or is it nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For safety, rewrite your code as:

```
[[APIClient objectManager] deleteObject:object path:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    if (success != nil) {
        success();
    }
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if (failure != nil) {
        failure([error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Because trying to execute a `nil` block is a bad thing.

Also, when you define the properties for `success` and `failure`, make sure you set them to be `copy` (not `strong`).

Comment: Spot on.  That was such an obvious error, I was just overthinking it.  Thanks for the clarity.